# AngularJS application problems appearance in Google search

Tags: angularjs, search, seo, google-search

I have a personal project which consumes my free time and effort for about a year without significant profit. I have problems with it appearance in Google and would really appreciate to get help here.

This project (http://yuppi.com.ua - similar to craiglist in US) is WEB-based AngularJS 1.2 application that uses PHP rest API hosted on GoDaddy.  And in order to make this application popular it have to be very visible in internet and very searchable in Google and users have to be able to share pages via social networks or skype.

According to Google specification, google crawlers doesn't run javascript to get content of a web page before index, so I've added _escaped_fragment_ page that displays content of web page without javascript. For example:

```
Page: http://yuppi.com.ua/#!/items/sub/18/_
Dirty : yuppi.com.ua/?_escaped_fragment_=/items/sub/18/_
```

This dirty page will be redirected here where google will see content.

```
 http://yuppi.com.ua/server/crawler_proxy/routee.php?path=/items/sub/18/
```

So basically I have two versions on HTML file for that page. One version is the one that available to users, which has styles, a lot more HTML tags etc. And the second is the version for Google crawler - very light-weight without any styles. And I am expecting to see clean link to my site in Google, not dirty.

So, If to search all links to a web site in Google you will see that one of the links displays it's "dirty" state.
[image]

Another problem is sharing links in Skype.
When I send a link to someone, I am expecting that this link will be transformed to thumbnail image but it is not happens. Instead I see ungly link to my web site.

Please help me to understand how to make happy everyone: users, google crawler, GoDaddy and me.

Answer (score -1):

I was encountering the same problems last year with a big project and we ended to use : https://prerender.io/.

It's a prerendering system that work with a phantomjs browser to detect bot request and render a full html template. It does also instanciate a cache service to not render again a template that haven't change.

Hope it help's.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't switch from PHP to NodeJS because of Godaddy.

Comment: did you see they also have php plugins ?

Comment: I am not looking something that you can buy, There should be nice solution for that. Or this is a bug that should be handled by Google team.